# How to store an List<Book> in text-based storage

Tags: java, arraylist, text

I'm working on a library management system when the data about the student is stored in a text file (student.txt) in the below form (ID::Name::Email):

```
1::James Bond::james@bond.com::
```

Now I want to issue books to the students and in the data class, I have added a List of type Book (Book data class also has a similar model (ID, Title, Author)).

```
public class Student {
   private int id;
   private String name;
   private String email;
   private final List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Here is the `student.txt` file:

```
1::James Bond::james@bond.com::
2::Mona Lisa::mona@lisa.com::
```

***How could I store multiple books in the same text-based form which I can later correspond to as an ArrayList?***

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use a database like perhaps...SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

If one `Book` can only be held by one `Student`, but one `Student` can hold many `Book`s then it's a one-to-many relationship. In that case you can add an extra column to students.txt with comma separated book ID's. Or an extra column to `books.txt` for the `student ID` who is currently holding the book.

If one `Book` can be held by many `Student`s at once then it's a many-to-many relationship and you can create a third text file `student-book.txt` which has two columns `book ID` and `student ID`.

In real world solution this is a perfect use case for SQL database where each file would be a table with foreign key constraints. Then you could use transactions and be sure that data is consistent.

Answer (score -1):

First, you **should** use some database. But let's try to answer it on file storage level.

I'm not sure if you really need to use those `::` but I would suggest to **use a JSON format** entry for each line. You have libraries for this that are ready to use (like Jackson) so it's easy to serialize and deserialize lists, nested objects, timestamps etc:

```
{"id": 1, "name": "James Bond", "email": "james@bond.com", "books": [{"title": "one"},{"title":"two"}]}
```

Otherwise, if you **really** need to stick with this format using `::`, which I discourage, you can store the list as JSON like this:

```
1::James Bond::james@bond.com::[{"title": "one"},{"title":"two"}]
```

The last part can be then parsed by Jackson as List.

Comment: We don't know the relation between `Book` and `Student`. It's very likely a Many-To-Many relationship and json/xml formats are really not that great at handling this type of relation. Even if it is an One-To-Many relationship I would recommend storing the data in a table oriented format. Preferably an embedded SQL database like SQLlite or H2 or alternatively an CSV oriented format like OP is using right now. A "one-file" solution is great for data tranfer, but not so great for classic CRUD operations.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes - I'm answering the question here, along with its constraints. I marked that he should use DB, but the question was about how to do it in specified format.